# nginx SSL Subdomain Rewrite

Tags: nginx, redirect

I want to rewrite https requests to **https://www** to **https://**. I'm trying to do something like this, but it doesn't seem to work for https:

```
server {
   listen 443;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sslchain.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.key;

   server_name www.nginx.com;
   rewrite ^ https://nginx.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you actually getting?

Comment: My certificate only works with the http://nginx.com version of the URL so then Firefox has that certificate warning page saying the certificate isn't trusted...

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting an SSL warning, you will need separate certs for www.example.com and example.com: these are different entities, as far as the certificate is concerned (i.e., the server name must match the Common Name for the certificate exactly).

One option may be to use [Subject Alternate Names](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm), though, depending on the type of browsers you expect to visit your site, that may not work (i.e., mobile browsers may be more finicky).  This essentially allows one certificate to be used for several different server names.

If you've already bought your cert, that may be a problem, too.

Comment: As stated I had to create/download another certificate for the `www` subdomain since I also had another subdomain that was using a different cert.